# Can I use Dockerfiles in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

Can I use a DOCKERFILE in my current Repo to be used as Image in the CI process?

REPO ROOT in Gitlab

```
.gitlab-ci.yml
DOCKERFILE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [build the Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) image with a Gitlab runner, [push it](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#using-the-gitlab-container-registry) to the Gitlab Registry, and then use it in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

Comment: How to push it to gitlab instead of dockerhub?

Comment: @xetrasu if you are using the Gitlab.com registry, do `docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com`. You can follow this guide: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html, just replace registry.example.com with registry.gitlab.com

Comment: Thank you so much ! @rpadovani

Comment: Is this the only way? Seems pretty complicate :-| The gitlab registry can also be used if I have my own Gitlab Server running, right?

Comment: @Isengo you can run registry on you own GitLab - it's described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/container_registry.html